# Linux Command Structure

Tags: linux, shell, unix, command

Can anyone tell me is there any simple rule or site which can help me to learn the options in command structure of Linux. Like  "ls -a [file name] "  here i am confused that is there any way to learn the -a type things,are they universal for other similar  commands too. 
it will be great if you can provide me some link regarding that.

Comment: For any command in Linux you can type `man <command>` to see all the available switches/options.

Comment: i have tried that and now each man page is describing the commands in such a way where it's almost impossible to understand the ground details of the command.in one line i m lost in using these options.

Comment: man pages are difficult to read at first, but there is no "magic solution" - just keep going, using man+google and you'll see that it gets easier every time!

Comment: You should try that question on [superuser](http://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Well, http://explainshell.com seems to have what you're looking for, but you should get used to checking man pages and Google.

Comment: thnx Andre Fernandese.

Answer (score 0):

Try help switch:

```
ls --help
```

for other commands any variant of "--help" or "-help" or "help" may trigger help to show. Also look for advanced options (like "git help -a"), when reading help.

Then try man:

```
man ls
```

where it's nice to know about "sections" and their meaning ([linux man pages](http://linux.die.net/man/)).

Answer (score 0):

There is no rule between all the commands. One you can easily remember is for example that `-r` or `-R` often refer to recursive.

But as stated in other comments, you should see the man page for each command you need the documentation for.
Some commands also offer a `--help` option, which generally shows the synopsis of the command and some useful and most used options.

http://explainshell.com/ is also a good website for simple commands but fails when using some composed functions with pipes for example. At least if you manage to decompose your command, it has more chances to work.